# Laravel integration testing for SSO NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, integration-testing

I need a help with my integration testing. I do have a project on localhost and SSO on localhost:8081 port. When I change base_url for SSO and send a request it throws Exception since the routing of login page not in the local project but inside SSO. How can I test external SSO and local project together?

```
 public function testLogin() 
 {
   config(['app.url' => 'http://192.168.33.11:8081']);

   $this->visit('/login?service_id=2')
       ->type('name', 'name')
       ->type('password', 'password');
       ->press('Log in')
       ->see('dashboard')
       ->onPage('dashboard.index');
  }
```

And the Exception

```
  There was 1 failure:
  1) ExampleTest::testLogin
  A request to [http://192.168.33.11:8081/login?service_id=2] failed. 
  Received status code [404].
  Caused by
  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in 
  C:\...vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:161
```

Comment: I changed my approach. I have received login token from SSO with using Guzzle and used the token to send a request to the local project. Auth::loginUsingId() can be used for sending a request as logged in user but in my case, I needed to check token.